# How can I set the Binding of two columns within a DataGrid to the values of two separate Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I am struggling to allocate saved values from two dictionaries within an object list to the values that are displayed in a datagrid.

I want to set Hours studied to WeeksWithHoursStudied.Value
and Hours Remaining to WeeksWithHoursStudied.Value

Any help is appreciated

Here is the xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeManager.ViewModules"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeManager"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="ViewModules"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        Background="#000b1e"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="ModuleGrid"
                  Width="650"
                  Margin="75,90,75,79"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Background="#cde6e6"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionChanged="ModuleGrid_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModuleCode"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding ModuleCode}"
                                    Header="Module Code"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModuleName"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding ModuleName}"
                                    Header="Module Name"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModuleHoursStudied"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding WeeksWithHourStudied}"
                                    Header="Hours Studied"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ModuleHoursRemaining"
                                    Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding WeeksWithHoursRemaining}"
                                    Header="Hours Remaining"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />


            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="RecordHoursBtn"
                Width="175"
                Height="40"
                Margin="0,0,0,20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Background="#eb0085"
                Click="RecordHoursBtn_Click"
                Content="Record Hours"
                FontSize="20"
                Foreground="#cde6e6">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#650136" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                    Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="20">
                        <!--  Adjust the CornerRadius value to control the rounding  -->
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

        <Button Name="BackHomeBtn"
                Width="40"
                Height="40"
                Margin="17,0,0,304"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Background="#eb0085"
                Click="BackHomeBtn_Click"
                Content="Back"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="#cde6e6">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#650136" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                    Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="20">
                        <!--  Adjust the CornerRadius value to control the rounding  -->
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <ComboBox Name="WeekComboBox"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="0,37,0,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="175"
                  SelectionChanged="WeekComboBox_SelectionChanged" />


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then the Module Class it is working from:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimeManagerClassLibrary
{
    // This class represents a module/course and its associated properties and methods.
    public class Module
    {
        // Private fields to store module information.
        private string moduleCode;
        private string moduleName;
        private int moduleCredits;
        private int moduleClassHoursPerWeek;
        private Dictionary<int, double> weeksWithHourStudied = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        private Dictionary<int, double> weeksWithHoursRemaining = new Dictionary<int, double>();

        // Default constructor for the Module class.
        public Module()
        {

        }

        public Module(string moduleCode, string moduleName, int moduleCredits, int moduleClassHoursPerWeek, Dictionary<int, double> weeksWithHourStudied, Dictionary<int, double> weeksWithHoursRemaining)
        {
            this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
            this.moduleName = moduleName;
            this.moduleCredits = moduleCredits;
            this.moduleClassHoursPerWeek = moduleClassHoursPerWeek;
            this.weeksWithHourStudied = weeksWithHourStudied;
            this.weeksWithHoursRemaining = weeksWithHoursRemaining;
        }


        // Parameterized constructor for the Module class.
        // Initializes the module with specified values


        // Property to get or set the module code.
        public string ModuleCode { get => moduleCode; set => moduleCode = value; }

        // Property to get or set the module name.
        public string ModuleName { get => moduleName; set => moduleName = value; }

        // Property to get or set the module credits.
        public int ModuleCredits { get => moduleCredits; set => moduleCredits = value; }

        // Property to get or set the module's class hours per week.
        public int ModuleClassHoursPerWeek { get => moduleClassHoursPerWeek; set => moduleClassHoursPerWeek = value; }
        public Dictionary<int, double> WeeksWithHourStudied { get => weeksWithHourStudied; set => weeksWithHourStudied = value; }
        public Dictionary<int, double> WeeksWithHoursRemaining { get => weeksWithHoursRemaining; set => weeksWithHoursRemaining = value; }





        public void CalculateWeeklyStudyHours(Module mod, Course cs, List<StudySession> savedSessions, int currentWeek)
        {
            Dictionary<int, double> tempDictStudied = mod.WeeksWithHourStudied;
            Dictionary<int, double> tempDictRemaining = mod.WeeksWithHoursRemaining;

            int numberOfWeeks = cs.NumberOfWeeks;
            double studyTarget = (ModuleCredits * 10.0 / numberOfWeeks) - ModuleClassHoursPerWeek;

            if (savedSessions != null)
            {
                foreach (var session in savedSessions)
                {
                    if (session.ModuleCode == moduleCode)
                    {
                        tempDictStudied[currentWeek] += session.HoursStudied;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var key in tempDictStudied)
            {
                tempDictRemaining[key.Key] = studyTarget - tempDictStudied[key.Key];
            }

            mod.WeeksWithHourStudied = tempDictStudied;
            mod.WeeksWithHoursRemaining = tempDictRemaining;
        }


        private static int getWeekNum(DateTime dt, DateTime d2)
        {

            TimeSpan difference = dt - d2;

            // Get the number of days as an integer
            int daysDifference = (int)difference.TotalDays;

            int weekNum = (daysDifference / 7) + 1;
            return weekNum;
        }

    }
}
```